# Azure: Failed to send bytes to XContainer wad-tracefiles

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

For some reason I get errors while using Diagnostics in Azure. The code of my (WCF) WebRole is:

```
public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // To enable the AzureLocalStorageTraceListner, uncomment relevent section in the web.config  
        DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
        diagnosticConfig.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        diagnosticConfig.Directories.DataSources.Add(AzureLocalStorageTraceListener.GetLogDirectory());
        diagnosticConfig.Directories.BufferQuotaInMB = 256;

        // Start diagnostics
        DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", diagnosticConfig);

        // Write trace line
        Trace.WriteLine("CUSTUM TRACE MESSAGE");

        // Start instance
        return base.OnStart();
    }
```

My Web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <system.diagnostics>     
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="AzureLocalStorage" type="WCFServiceWebRole1.AzureLocalStorageTraceListener, WCFServiceWebRole1"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics> 
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In the Compute Emulator I see the following error:

```
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Started
[Diagnostics]: Starting configuration channel polling
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-06-06T10:01:20.111Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6396
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6624
[MonAgentHost] Error:     NetTransport
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\shared\nettransport\src\xblobconnection.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     XBlobConnection::PutBytesXBlob
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1621
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffff80050023
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Failed to send bytes to XContainer wad-tracefiles
```

This error repeats several times. The "wad-tracefiles" container is added by the following code in the AzureLocalStorageTraceListener class:

```
public static DirectoryConfiguration GetLogDirectory()
    {
        DirectoryConfiguration directory = new DirectoryConfiguration();
        directory.Container = "wad-tracefiles";
        directory.DirectoryQuotaInMB = 10;
        directory.Path = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("WCFServiceWebRole1.svclog").RootPath;
        return directory;
    }
```

Why does writing trace messages fails in this scenario? When I look in my Storage with the Azure Storage Explorer the only table I see is the WADDirectoriesTable and not the the WADLogsTable. The "wad-tracefiles" blob does get created but that is not the place where I should find the Trace messages from my code.

Anyone, any idea? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you haven't used SetCurrentConfiguration() with your GetDefaultInitialConfiguration() to finally save the transfer time and log level. You must use the set of these API as below:

```
GetDefaultInitialConfiguration() 
SetCurrentConfiguration()
```

OR

```
GetCurrentConfiguration()
SetCurrentConfiguration()
```

Because of it the following line based configuration will not be saved in Diagnostics configuration:
    diagnosticConfig.Directories.DataSources.Add(AzureLocalStorageTraceListener.GetLogDirectory());

Use above suggestion and then see what happens.

I would also suggest to just create a very simple web or worker role hello world sample and add general TRACE Message by enabling Azure Diagnostics to see if that give you any error. This will prove if you have any issue with your SDK installation or Azure Storage Emulator or not as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply! The project I am using is a really simple WebRole with only one trace message so I can not strip any code out.

I tried your suggestion and you are right, I do not get any error messages anymore with the following code:

```
public override bool OnStart()
    {
        setDiagnostics();

        Trace.WriteLine("CUSTUM TRACE MESSAGE");

        // Start instance
        return base.OnStart();
    }

    private void setDiagnostics()
    {
        // Get diagnostics connectionstring
        string wadConnectionString = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString";
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(wadConnectionString));

        // Get the diagnostics configuration of the deployment and its role instances that are currently running
        DeploymentDiagnosticManager deploymentDiagnosticManager = new DeploymentDiagnosticManager(cloudStorageAccount, RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId);
        RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager roleInstanceDiagnosticManager = cloudStorageAccount.CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(
            RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId,
            RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name,
            RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);

        // Load diagnostics configuration
        DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagConfig = roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.GetCurrentConfiguration();

        // Get the default value if there is no config yet
        if (diagConfig == null)
            diagConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

        // Enable EventLogs
        diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");
        diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);
        diagConfig.WindowsEventLog.BufferQuotaInMB = 128;

        // Failed Request Logs
        diagConfig.Directories.DataSources.Add(AzureLocalStorageTraceListener.GetLogDirectory());
        diagConfig.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);
        diagConfig.Directories.BufferQuotaInMB = 128;

        // Crash Dumps
        CrashDumps.EnableCollection(true);

        // Set new configuration
        roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.SetCurrentConfiguration(diagConfig);

        // Start the DiagnosticMonitor
        DiagnosticMonitor.Start(wadConnectionString, diagConfig);
    }
```

When I look in which tables are present in the Azure Storage Explorer I only see the "WADDirectoriesTable" and the "WADWindowsEventLogsTable". Trace messages should come in the "WADLogsTable" right? So I see the Trace message in the Compute Emulator but I do not see them in my storage... any ideas why?

Comment: Yes Trace message will be stored at "WADLogsTable" in your Azure Table Storage. I have seen a race condition where a single message may not appear due to some reason. The best would be spawn a thread in your role and start writing Trace Message every 30 seconds and see if this changes this behavior. If it works or not let me know. I have some other things to try..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should add this as a comment to the answer and/or add it to the question. SO is not a forum; it uses a 1-Question + multiple answers format.